# Field Data Collection and Automation

Tags: open-source, data-analysis, data, collection-manager, land-surveying

My company deals with **Close Interval Surveys.** We are trying to limit the time spent in the office compiling reports once the source data is collected from the field. My question, is there some type of software that caters to the recording of **CIS** data or enables the users to input **stationing data** as recorded, then take that data and have it automatically append to some kind of **constructed PDF template** with assigned fields for stationing?

Comment: I think there are a lot of them out there. We have been using ofspro.com field service software and it has helped a lot. I think you can sign up for a free trial on their website. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

My company recently started using [OFSpro](http://ofspro.com/) for exactly what you are saying you are in need of. It is a great software for managing field services. The other thing we love about it is that they have an App that makes it super easy to keep up with things that are happening from the office and field. Check it out. You may be surprised on how helpful it is.